# "other user" Showing up on Logon Screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, user-accounts

For the past few days, I've had a new icon on the logon screen. Apart from my admin account, I now have an account labeled "other user", with just a frame and no user icon. What could be causing this, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: If you are using the main administrator account, I would suggest you create a new account to use. It will minimize your risk of virus crashing the whole OS and hacking. As for the "other User", it could have been poked at by an update by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Other User** is an option for you to login as another account. If you have ***any*** other accounts installed in the system other than the main user, you will have that. If you use the **built-in Administrator** account, the **Other User** will show up. The only way to get rid of it is to disable any accounts other than your main account.

Comment: All other accounts, including the guest, are disabled. This has only shown up recently; and I don't recall anything changing the user accounts.

Comment: I think it's user list corruption instead, check this: https://superuser.com/a/1404899/131936